# How Can I Stop GPS Tracking When I Press a Button in Android

Tags: android, gps

I want to stop GPS tracking when a user clicks on a specific button. How can I achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the `onPause()` method, call the method `removeUpdates()` on that `LocationListener`

Answer (score 1):

The following link can be useful to you

- [How do I stop GPS/location tracking when my Activity finishes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4070260/android-stop-gps-tracking-on-activity-finish)